# Is there an archive of old Ubuntu files such as rootfs-ubuntu-12.10-0.8.0.tar.lzma?

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

goo.im and rabids.org are dead. However is there some other source for old files from 2012?

I also posted a related question elsewhere: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1110045-where-did-gooim-and-rabidsorg-go/

(tagged as nvdia due to tf700t having a tegra)

Comment: Can try this link, http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ .  From this Question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Google, rootfs-ubuntu-12.10-0.8.0.tar.lzma → https://uploadedtrend.com/file/9330423_19499504/ubuntu_12.10_completo.iso.html